# Facing issues with HttpResponseRedirect in Django

Tags: django

I am creating a basic login functionality for the user.If the login is successful I am redirecting the user to my index page which I have hardcoded in HttpResponseRedirect. But once I click the login Button its saying,

TypeError at /Login/
login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

index page in urls.py id defined as below,

url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

Below is the code for my index view and login view:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'authentication_app/index.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('name')
        password=request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Your Account has become Invalid')
        else:
            print('Someone tried to login with wrong credentials:{0},{1}'.format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse('Username and Password mismatch.Please enter valid credentials')

    else:
        return render(request,'authentication_app/login.html',{})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the **function name** from `login()` to something like `user_login()`.

```
def user_login(request):
```

It is **conflicting** with `login(request,user)` used here.

Comment: @Deepak, you can select the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the imported login to another name
like

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
```

user auth_login for perform login